# Xamarin Activity vs Application

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin

Whats the difference b/w using Activity vs Application in Xamarin? Why would one want to use one approach over another?

For example, when I create a new Xamarin Form project in VS I get the follow:

```
[Activity(Label = "eApprove Main Activity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/eA_icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
            ...
}
```

I have also seen examples on internet where people are using Application class as their main Entry point:

```
namespace MyExpenses.Android
{
       [Application(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light") ]
       public class MyExpensesApplication : Application
       {
               public static Activity CurrentActivity { get; set; }

               public MyExpensesApplication(IntPtr handle, global::Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transer)
                  :base(handle, transer)
              {
              }

              public override void OnCreate()
              {
                  base.OnCreate();
              }
       }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should examine the official Android Developer docs, understand about the `Application` class and `Activity` class as defined in Java and *THEN* go back to xamarin and c#. I'm a C# programmer but when I chose to program for Android I chose to use Java instead of using cross-platform tools like xamarin. I suspect I know a great deal more about Android having done it that way.

Comment: I don't have the luxury to go through the learning curve and learn java. I work for a Microsoft shop and Xamarin is what the shop is going to use. That said, your advice is still valid and I appreciate that though I still believe Xamarin has its place in the technology stack.

Comment: There isn't really that much of a learning curve. When Microsoft created C# they basically ripped off Java - if you can program in C# then Java isn't that far from it. There *ARE* some differences but on the whole, not many. Your question is about the `Application` class vs the `Activity` class - in this case Xamarin is irrelevant it's just a development tool. `Application` and `Activity` are core classes in Android and unless you read the Android docs you'll have trouble understanding their purpose.

Comment: I'm with @Squonk on this one. Although you are developing in Xamarin, having a good understanding of the native classes is very important for development.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you do not confuse a classical Xamarin.Android app with the android portion of a Xamarin.Forms app. My quick and easy answer/recommendation would be that you would have one Application class per App project per platform and as many Activities as you like. The application is your entry point that kicks of any numbers activities based on your needs...